# How can i set 'scrollEnabled' property of ScrollView based on animatedValue?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I use Reanimated 2.4.1.

I tried to do like this:

```
const scrollEnabled = useAnimatedStyle(false)

return (
  <Animated.ScrollView scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled.value}>
  ....
  </Animated.ScrollView>
)
```

and like this:

```
const someAnimatedValue = useAnimatedStyle(false);

const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
  return {
    scrollEnabled: someAnimatedValue.value
  }
})

return (
  <Animated.ScrollView {...animatedProps}>
  ....
  </Animated.ScrollView>
)
```

but none of this works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [useSharedValue](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/hooks/useSharedValue) for animated value.
Another point is that [animatedProps](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/hooks/useAnimatedProps) usage is not correct.

```
const someAnimatedValue = useSharedValue(false);

const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
  return {
    scrollEnabled: someAnimatedValue.value
  }
})

return (
  <Animated.ScrollView animatedProps={animatedProps}>
  ....
  </Animated.ScrollView>
)
```